# How to fix the Data Transfer (CLOSE) I FIGURED IT OUT

Tags: modifiers, uv, layers

Okay, I finally got the one problem fixed now it's another one. So sorry I'm such a noob! Anyhow, as it shows in the picture when I go to do a data transfer zero uv_0 or uv_1 shows up to apply. Where have they gone to? Any ideas on how to fix this without starting the project over?[image]

Comment: If you solved your problem, then please write an answer in the answer section so that other users may learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Source Object and then click on your reference or whatever you named it. Then you can click on UV's and the layers will show up.